# Python only get specific value in json

Tags: python, json, google-api, ocr

I am using the google vision api on python to get text on images,
the api returns this json text:

```
text_annotations {
  locale: "en"
  description: "SPEED\n"
  bounding_poly {
    vertices {
      x: 6
      y: 60
    }
    vertices {
      x: 151
      y: 60
    }
    vertices {
      x: 151
      y: 117
    }
    vertices {
      x: 6
      y: 117
    }
  }
}
text_annotations {
  description: "SPEED"
  bounding_poly {
    vertices {
      x: 6
      y: 60
    }
    vertices {
      x: 151
      y: 60
    }
    vertices {
      x: 151
      y: 117
    }
    vertices {
      x: 6
      y: 117
    }
  }
}
```

How do I only get the `description:`  value?

I have been trying: `esp = response['description']`

But it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\username\ai2.py", line 27, in <module>
    resp = response['description']
TypeError: 'AnnotateImageResponse' object is not subscriptable
```

Full code:

```
import io
import os
import json

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r"C:\Users\fkahd\OneDrive\Bureau\zefoy\vision-apixxxxxxxxxxxx.json"

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\fkahd\OneDrive\Bureau\zefoy\captchas\captcha(22).png")

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.text_detection(image=image)  # returns TextAnnotation
resp = response['description']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the text wanted by adding:

```
print(response.text_annotations[0].description)
```

thanks for your "help"

Answer (score -1):

JSON filed in python are similarly interpreted as dictionaries and you can get the value of 'description' in the similar manner. Here's what you have to do:

```
var_name = file_name['description']
```

The `file_name` is supposed to be the name of the opened json file.

Comment: i get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\username\ai2.py", line 26, in <module>
    var_name = resp['description']
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\username\venv\lib\site-packages\proto\marshal\collections\repeated.py", line 119, in __getitem__
    return self._marshal.to_python(self._pb_type, self.pb[key])
TypeError: indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Did you load the file properly? I mean `json.load()`

Comment: how do I use `json.load()`, I added the code in the question, could you tell wherer and how to place it

Comment: with: `response = client.text_detection(image=image)  # returns TextAnnotation
json.loads(response)
resp = response['description']` it tells me: `File "C:\Users\fkahd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not AnnotateImageResponse`

Comment: Man, you need to load it properly. Try this:
`import json
with open('path_to_file/file_name.json', 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)`